# Conversion of a character string to a date

Tags: r, string, date

I have a character string that I am trying to convert to a date. Ultimately, I want to extract the year and month into a new column. I am having difficulties with the format. The code below returns NA as the date value.

```
Dates <- c("Mon, 18 Jan 2016 13:04:00 +0000","Sat, 16 Jan 2016 02:59:26 +0000",
           "Wed, 13 Jan 2016 10:08:48 +0000", "Thu, 07 Jan 2016 20:27:39 +0000")
str(Dates)
NewDates <- as.Date(Dates,format = "%a %d %b %Y")
str(NewDates)
```

Is there a different format I should be using? Do I need to strip out some of the characters prior to conversion? Below is a sample of the string and the conversion statement.

Comment: Your `format` in `as.Date` must follow the current format.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you simply missed a comma:

```
Dates <- c("Mon, 18 Jan 2016 13:04:00 +0000","Sat, 16 Jan 2016 02:59:26 +0000",
       "Wed, 13 Jan 2016 10:08:48 +0000", "Thu, 07 Jan 2016 20:27:39 +0000")
str(Dates)
NewDates <- as.Date(Dates,format = "%a, %d %b %Y")
str(NewDates)
```

This works for me.

Comment: Thanks - I thought I had tried that approach. I must have gotten the spacing wrong. Your solution works for me too.